It's there any way to get the thumbnail from the sai2 file?
For example, you can use some means to parse psd files and export them into image files, but how does PaintTool SAI2 get thumbnail?
I tried x64dbg and IDA Pro to debug sai2.exe and got the folder C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\SYSTEMAX Software Development\SAI2 Demo\thumbs-test01, it looks like it might be related
